# Run SAS from command line without GUI

Tags: sas

How can I write and run SAS code from **linux** command line (eg, the terminal, from which all other programs can be executed)?

Eg, use a text editor to create a file like 'file.sas'  then run in the command line

'sas file.sas'

Ie, can I run without using the sas command line and user interface

For example, in python you can write a .py script in a text editor and execute using python file.py

Comment: `sas program_name.sas` is the correct method to call a program from the command line. What is the issue you're experiencing? Or why do you think it's not working.

Comment: SAS is not open source, but has a body of knowledge that goes back to the 70's. You can find many resources on lexjansen.com or communities.sas.com but not many users use SO for SAS questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can run a sas script from terminal, without the sas user interface.  Also you can put this into the sas script

```
ods pdf file = 'op.pdf';
```

So when calling from terminal, don't need to direct output via `>>`

Comment: Because it's not the answer to the question asked. And please use full words and sentences. Trying to understand acronyms across multiple fields isn't fun at the best of times. Is OP here 'Original Poster' as commonly used in forums?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you can locate the SAS Foundation installation folder you can execute a sas session from the terminal.

See sample command below: opening a sas session and specifying the file to execute and where to save the log file:

```
/sas/940/SASFoundation/9.4/sas /projects/program1.sas -log "/projects/program1.log"
```

SAS Command line documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation//cdl/en/hostunx/67929/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0a9pg9dddvvbkn1rll5kefgvr2q.htm)

Answer (score 0):

On your SAS command line you can `-set` an environment variable that is used by your program.

```
sas ... -set pdf_file op.pdf -sysin myProgram.sas

myProgram.sas
-------------
...
filename pdf_out = "%sysget(pdf_file)";
ods pdf file=pdf_out ...;
proc ...
```

Comment: One can also use `sysparm` to do a similar sort of thing without creating environment variables.